# Check if a character appears more than once in a string using charAt() and loop

Tags: java

The code is giving characters for consecutive appearances and not for non-consecutive repetition of a character in a string. Using function can be easy but I want to use loop and use `charAt` in it to compare.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {        
    if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(i+1)) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: You need nested loop there.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun A `Map` would make it not O(n^2) ;)

Comment: Even an array could do with 256 space and you can find in most-efficient way.

Comment: it wont give a right answer.if you take eg abac ....in this when i=1 it enters j loop j=1 then i(1) =b,j(1)=b and hence b=b and count will increase.but as you can see only "a" is appearing twice in the eg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
  for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length; j++) {

    if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j)){
       count++;
    }
}    
return count;
}
```

Comment: sounds like a homework .. instead of direct codes better give some hints :)

Comment: it wont give a right answer.if you take eg abac ....in this when i=1 it enters j loop j=1 then i(1) =b,j(1)=b and hence b=b and count will increase.but as you can see only "a" is appearing twice in the eg.

Comment: Yes you are right.  I have changed the intialization if `j` to be `i + 1`

Answer (score 3):

Your code will throw [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

You need a nested loop, because now you're checking if there are two adjacency equal characters.

Do something like that (I won't show you a solution, but I'll guide you):

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
   another loop with index j {
      if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j)){
         count++;
      } 
   }
}
```

However, as suggested in comments by @BrianRoach, if you use a `Map`, you'll get a better solution:

You can have a `Character` *key* and a *value* of `Integer` that indicates how many times a `char` appears in the String.

---

**Edit**:

After your edit, you only need to change the loop condition to `str.length() - 1`.

Comment: @user3057435 I don't think so.

Comment: According the OP, count should only be increment if the next value is the same.  If `i` if going all the way to `str.length` then what is to going to compare with ? `j` will also be `str.length` and then will be comparing the same char.

Comment: @user2310289 He edited his question after I've answered.

Comment: @ᴍaroun ᴍaroun it wont give a right answer.if you take eg abac ....in this when i=1 it enters j loop j=1 then i(1) =b,j(1)=b and hence b=b and count will increase.but as you can see only "a" is appearing twice in the eg.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late in time, but rather than complex responses I came up with this:

```
public static boolean isitIsogram(String word){
    int count = 0;
    char check = ' ';
    if(word == "" || word == null){
        return false;
    }
    String newWord = word.toLowerCase();
    char [] checkWord = newWord.toCharArray();
    for (char i : checkWord){
        if(check == i)
            return false;
        for(char j : checkWord){
            if(i == j){
                count++;
                if(count > 1){
                    check = i;
                }

            }

        }count = 0;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This function would also cater for empty and null string cases