# How to count no. of different characters in a string using loop and charAt?

Tags: java

This gives correct output only if all the characters are different but fails when there are some repeated characters after the first index character. Please guide for counting different chars in a string

```
public int diff(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    char ch = str.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (ch != str.charAt(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count+1;
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545443/check-if-a-character-appears-more-than-once-in-a-string-using-charat-and-loop

More or less you are trying to finish your homework with different questions

Comment: give us example please ?

Comment: I am trying to do a set of problems from  strings topic

Answer (score 1):

You just have to check, if the current char is not in the String before the current position.

This should do the trick:

```
public static int diff(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char current = str.charAt(i);
        if (!str.substring(0, i).contains(current+"")) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to remember which characters you encountered so far. You can store them in a Set, like so:

```
public static int diff(String str) {
    Set<Character> chars = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (!chars.contains(ch)) {
            chars.add(ch);
        }
    }
    return chars.size();
}
```

Comment: Was my idea. You was too fast.
Exactly this is the solution. Remember already checked chars.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious approach is to collect seen chars in a set, but using a sorted char array is probably more efficient.

```
char[] ary = str.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(ary);
int count = 0, prev = -1;
for (char c : ary) if (c != prev) { count++; prev = c; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're only comparing the current char with the immediately before and no with all of them. You could fix it like this:

```
 public int diff(String str) {
   int count = 0;
   // Loop through all the array
   for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      boolean seen = false
      // Loop trying to match all the previous with the current
      for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i)) {
            seen = true
        }
      }
      // Count it if it's not been seen before
      if seen == false {
         count++
      }
   }
   return count+1;
}
```

What this does is try to match current char `str.charAt(i)` with all the previous
`str.charAt(j)`. Let me know if it's not clear.

It's not the most efficient approach, but I was trying to match what you're doing in your code and explain what it was incorrect with it. Probably a shorted array will be faster for this.